# Custom Font not displaying in my webpage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, fonts

I have a particular set fonts that I want to implement on a web application that I am building for my class project. Right now, I have it all hosted on GitHub via *GitHub Pages*. The index page currently uses 4 CSS files, one for [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), the general CSS file for the whole application, Bootstrap's CSS file, and then another CSS file specifically for it.

On the general web app CSS file, named custom.css, I have the following code:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

@type-face {
font-family: FuturaStd-HeavyOblique;
src: url('fonts/FUTURASTD-HEAVYOBLIQUE.OTF');
}

@
type-face {
    font-family: COUTURE Bold;
    src: url('fonts/COUTURE-Bold.ttf');
}

.body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And here is my index.css file:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/flyknit.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
}

.indexTitle {
    font-family: FuturaStd-HeavyOblique;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 500%;
}

.buttonBox {
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: FuturaStd-HeavyOblique;
}

#bbText {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    color: white    
}
```

At first, the fonts were running fine on my computer, because I have them installed. But if I was to run the page through GitHub, the font does not show up. And recently, the font won't even run from my own computer. What did I do wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you try this in your fonts.css

```
@font-face {   
font-family: 'FuturaStd-HeavyOblique'; 
src: url('fonts/FUTURASTD-HEAVYOBLIQUE.OTF');
}
```

call it back with

```
font-family: 'FuturaStd-HeavyOblique';
```

Not sure if quotation marks matter, but I believe `@type-face` should be `@font-face`

Comment: I don't know what it is then, what I do know: That I had trouble with that too a couple of months ago, redownloading the font from somewhere else fixed the issue. Is your fonts folder outside of your CSS folder? Because maybe you need to correct your URL pathing.

Comment: My fonts folder is outside my CSS folder. I'll see about correct the URL pathing.

Comment: url('../fonts') if your fonts folder is 1 below your custom.css otherwise place fonts in the same folder as your css. Hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: I changed the URL pathing, and still nothing changed. I wonder if it may be my computer. I'll try on a different one soon. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but have you checked if your otf isn't corrupted? Or have you sorted it out already?

Comment: I haven't checked if it's corrupted. I'll look into that.